# OpenCV training and testing Face Recognition with Python error

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I get this error when i try to recognize the images from `unknowns/UNKNOWNS` with the images in att_faces database.

OpenCV Error:

> Bad argument (Wrong input image size. Reason: Training and Test images must be of equal size! Expected an image with 10304 elements, but got 92.) in predict, file /home/irum/OpenCv/modules/contrib/src/facerec.cpp, line 623
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "rough.py", line 62, in 
>           prediction  = model.predict(images2)
>       cv2.error: /home/irum/OpenCv/modules/contrib/src/facerec.cpp:623: error: (-5) Wrong input image size. Reason: Training and Test images must be of equal size! Expected an image with 10304 elements, but got 92. in function predict

But the images in both the folders are same with and height. They are actually same images of cropped faces using Haar Cascades in different python script but now that i am using both folders for recognition purpose it is giving me error. i just dont understand why?
below is my code that i am using.

```
import cv2, sys, numpy, os
import json
size = 4
fn_dir2 = 'unknown'
fn_haar = 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
fn_dir = 'att_faces'
path2='/home/irum/Desktop/Face-Recognition/thakarrecog/UNKNOWNS'
path='/home/irum/Desktop/Face-Recognition/thakarrecog/att_faces'

# Prepare Train Set
print('Training...')

(images, lables, names, id) = ([], [], {}, 0)

for (subdirs, dirs, files) in os.walk(fn_dir):
    for subdir in dirs:
        names[id] = subdir 
        subjectpath = os.path.join(fn_dir, subdir) 
        for filename in os.listdir(subjectpath):
            path = subjectpath + '/' + filename
            lable = id
            images.append(cv2.imread(path, 0))
            lables.append(int(lable))
        id += 1

(images, lables) = [numpy.array(lis) for lis in [images, lables]]

# Create FisherFace Recognizer
model = cv2.createFisherFaceRecognizer()

# Load TrainSet
model.train(images, lables)

# Prepare Test Data
# Create a list of images and a list of corresponding names

(images2, lables2, names2, id) = ([], [], {}, 0)


for (subdirs, dirs, files) in os.walk(fn_dir2):
    for subdir in dirs:
        names2[id] = subdir 
        subjectpath = os.path.join(fn_dir2, subdir)  
        for filename in os.listdir(subjectpath):

            path = subjectpath + '/' + filename
            lable = id
            images2.append(cv2.imread(path, 0))
            lables2.append(int(lable))

            # Convert images2 to numpy
            images2 = numpy.array(images2)

            # Try to recognize/predict the face
            prediction  = model.predict(images2)

            print "Recognition Prediction" ,prediction
            result = {
                'face': {

                 'distance': prediction,
                 'coords': {
                   'x': str(faces[0][0]),
                   'y': str(faces[0][1]),
                   'width': str(faces[0][2]),
                   'height': str(faces[0][3])
                    }
                }
              }
            print "1 Result of Over all Prediction" ,result
        id += 1
```